# Как написать sql запрос, выводящий букву, находящуюся в середине строки

Tags: sql, sql-server

Необходимо написать запрос, который выводит букву, находящуюся в середине заданной строки (например, сон - вывести букву "о"); если количество слов в строке четное, то необходимо вывести левую букву из середины (например, супы - вывести букву "у").

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Примера созданной таблицы нет, поэтому вот так:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Nomenclature](
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY];

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Nomenclature]
           ([Name])
     VALUES
           (N'Сон'),
           (N'Супы'),
           (N'Корона'),
           (N'Сервера');
```

Запрос:

```
SELECT
   Name,
   CASE LEN(Name)%2
      WHEN 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Name, LEN(Name)/2+1, 1)
      WHEN 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Name, LEN(Name)/2, 1)
   END Rezult
FROM Nomenclature;
```

Результат:

| Name | Rezult |
| --- | --- |
| Сон | о |
| Супы | у |
| Корона | р |
| Сервера | в |

В следующий раз указывайте версию сервера, для точностей.

Comment: Мне кажется можно брать `(LEN(Name)+1)/2` и округлять до целого, просто не помню как округление в `SQL`. Тогда не нужно будет ветвление.

Answer (score 1):

```
SUBSTRING(YouColumn, CEILING(LEN(YouColumn) / 2.0), 1)
```